# Class versus list (accessors coding style)

Tags: python, list, class, coding-style

I'm relatively new to Python and, to better understand the Zen of Python as well as its advised coding style, I need to remove this doubt from my mind.

Suppose I have to define and instantiate a data structure representing a person. This will have the following properties:

1. Name
2. Age

I can think of two different approaches to represent this instance:

1. Define a class
2. Use a list

The former is trivial (following one possible example):

```
class Person:
  def __init__(self, name, age):
    self.name = name
    self.age = age

person = Person('David', 25)
# getter
print(person.name, person.age)
# setter
person.age = 27
```

The latter consists on a list of properties that I'd use in the following way:

```
NAME = 0
AGE = 1

person = ['David', 25]
# getter
print(person[NAME], person[AGE])
# setter
person[AGE] = 27
```

Which is the closest approach to the Zen of Python?

Comment: I'd definitely use a `class`.

Comment: Your 2nd way can actually be used with a namedtuple, which would be more pythonic than depending on constants.

Comment: or use a dictionary ...

Comment: @AlexThornton Why you'd go with `class`?

Comment: @Nick It just makes sense in my head. A `Person` is a `type` of `object`, that has the _attributes_ `name` and `age`.

Comment: The downside to a list is that there is nothing obvious that says NAME and AGE have anything to do with the list you generate. Its really just "tribal knowledge" that is lost over time. Classes formalize the relationship.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just about the most compact and convenient way to make a python "thing" for some data, is [`collections.namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple), which offers some of the explicit self documentation benefits of a class, but the convenience of simple python types (like a dict):

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> Person = namedtuple("Person", "name age")
>>> Person("Alice", 33)
Person(name='Alice', age=33)
>>> alice = _
>>> bob = Person(age=27, name="Bob")
>>> alice == bob
False
>>> bob.age
27
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you ask about the zen of python, I'd say that either class or namedtuple is better. See this part of The Zen of Python:

> If the implementation is hard to explain, it's a bad idea.

Its easier to explain: "This class represents a person" than: "This list represents a person, to access properties of the person you need to access constants of this module and use them as indices".